# How to deploy express app following esmodule on vercel

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, deployment, vercel

I have seen many examples written in common js which are deployed onto vercel. But I miss example which shows usage of es module express application.

I have a simple application:

`server.mjs`

```
import express from "express";
import postsRouter from "./routes/posts.js";
import connectDB from "./config/db.js";
import cors from "cors";
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors());

connectDB();

app.use("/api/posts", postsRouter);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("Backend of the app is now accessible ");
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});

export default app;
```

`package.json`

```
{
    "type": "module",
    "dependencies": {
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
        "express": "^4.18.2",
        "mongoose": "^7.6.3"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "nodemon server.mjs"
    }
}
```

`vercel.json`

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [{ "src": "server.mjs", "use": "@now/node" }],
    "routes": [
        {
            "src": "/(.*)",
            "dest": "server.mjs"
        }
    ]
}
```

I get error saying

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /var/task/backend/server.mjs not supported.
Instead change the require of /var/task/backend/server.mjs to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at /var/task/___now_launcher.js:26:28
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/___now_launcher.js:74:7)
    at _tryRequireFile (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1002:37)
    at _tryRequire (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1052:25)
    at _loadUserApp (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1081:22)
    at UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1119:27)
    at start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1282:42)
    at file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1288:7 {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /var/task/backend/server.mjs not supported.
Instead change the require of /var/task/backend/server.mjs to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at /var/task/___now_launcher.js:26:28
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/___now_launcher.js:74:7)
    at _tryRequireFile (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1002:37)
    at _tryRequire (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1052:25)
    at _loadUserApp (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1081:22)
    at UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1119:27)
    at start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1282:42)
    at file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1288:7 {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 1
Runtime.ExitError
```

I am not able to figure out the usage of `require()` in the entire application which the vercel is complaining about. Any leads or solutions would be really helpful.